# Not able to match the regex

Tags: regex, splunk

I need to write the regex to fetch the details from the following data

```
Type     Time(s)  Ops          TPS(ops/s)   Net(M/s)   Get_miss   Min(us)  Max(us)    Avg(us)    Std_dev    Geo_dist
Period   5        145443       29088        22.4       37006      352      116302     6600       7692.04    4003.72
Global   10       281537       28153        23.2       41800      281      120023     6797       7564.64    4212.93
```

The above is the log which i get from a log file
I have tried writing the reg ex to get the details in the table format but could not get.
Below is the reg ex which i tried.
`Type[\s+\S+].+\n(?<time>[\d+\S+\s+]+)[\s+\S+].*Period`
When it comes to Period keyword the regex fails

Comment: Thanks for sharing your efforts, what is your expected output, kindly do update your question with same, thank you.

Comment: Hi, I have no Splunk to test right now, but you sould check wether your Splunk can match over multiple lines ( suggested short read : https://community.splunk.com/t5/Splunk-Search/Regex-to-return-text-over-multiple-lines/m-p/355474 ) : "You need to prefix your RegEx with (?ms) which will cause the . token to include [\r\n] and also to process multi-line." Exemple given in the link : `rex "(?ms)(?P<ERR>^.*?(?=at))"`

Comment: What do you mean by `the details in the table format`? @Vulpo There is no `at` in the string.

Comment: Why must the solution be a regex?  The `multikv` command will parse the table for you.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

If for some reason [RichG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2227420/richg)'s suggestion of using `multikv` doesn't work, the following should:

```
| rex field=_raw "(?<type>\w+)\s+(?<time>[\d\.]+)\s+(?<ops>[\d\.]+)\s+(?<tps>[\d\.]+)\s+(?<net>[\d\.]+)\s+(?<get_miss>[\d\.]+)\s+(?<min>[\d\.]+)\s+(?<max>[\d\.]+)\s+(?<avg>[\d\.]+)\s+(?<std_dev>[\d\.]+)\s+(?<geo_dist>[\d\.]+)"
```

Where is your data coming from?